# Change default URL (or permalinks) in the back-end

Tags: permalinks, wp-admin, urls, add-menu-page

Assume I have the following code

```
add_menu_page('My Title', 'My Title', 'publish_posts', 'my-slug', function () {
    require_once ('path/to/render/page.php');
});
```

This code will add a menu item to the side bar of the admin section, and if you click on that new menu item, and inspect the URL,

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-slug
```

Everything is great so far.

Now my question: Is it possible to change the default URL above to something maybe like this?

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/my-slug
```

Or this?

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/page/my-slug
```

Or even this?

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php/page/my-slug
```

Basically, I do NOT want the query variables to be displayed as shown in the default setup. In other words, can I change the permalinks for the back-end?

Thank you.